# Manipulating Javascript Data to Toggle Series on D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am following this example on flot (http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/series-toggle/index.html) to apply the concept onto D3.js.

my data looks like this :

```
[ { "sourceA" : 28, "sourceB": 25, "sourceC": 20, "date": "29-Apr-13", 
"sourceA" : 15, "sourceB": 23, "sourceC": 54, "date": "29-May-13",
"sourceA" : 23, "sourceB": 43, "sourceC": 23, "date": "29-Jun-13",
}]
```

I have followed the source code of the above example to set up the checkboxes ("sourceA", "sourceB", etc). However, I'm stuck with how to manipulate data using "plotAccordingToChoices" function.

Ie, if the sourceA checkbox was selected, the function should change the data to:

```
[ { "sourceA" : 28, "date": "29-Apr-13", 
"sourceA" : 15, "date": "29-May-13",
"sourceA" : 23, "date": "29-Jun-13",
}]
```

Sample code from the example - http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/series-toggle/index.html

```
// insert checkboxes 
    var choiceContainer = $("#choices");
    $.each(datasets, function(key, val) {
        choiceContainer.append("<br/><input type='checkbox' name='" + key +
            "' checked='checked' id='id" + key + "'></input>" +
            "<label for='id" + key + "'>"
            + val.label + "</label>");
    });

    choiceContainer.find("input").click(plotAccordingToChoices);

    function plotAccordingToChoices() {

        var data = [];

        choiceContainer.find("input:checked").each(function () {
            var key = $(this).attr("name");
            if (key && datasets[key]) {
                data.push(datasets[key]);
            }
        });

        if (data.length > 0) {
            $.plot("#placeholder", data, {
                yaxis: {
                    min: 0
                },
                xaxis: {
                    tickDecimals: 0
                }
            });
        }
    }

    plotAccordingToChoices();
```

Comment: I suggest the you check out the tutorials and examples on the D3 website. This will be much more helpful than porting something complex like this.

Comment: Actually, I think my question is more of how to manipulate that data to select only 1 or 2 sources. It's too specific to look at D3 websites for answers.

Comment: Have edited the question to better reflect where I'm seeking help from. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code of your filter function would look something like the following.

```
function filter(json, attrName) {
  var newJson = [];
  json.forEach(function(d) {
    newJson.push({ "date": d.date, attrName: d[attrName] });
  });
  return newJson;
}
```